# Mysql - A simple database design question

Tags: mysql, database-design

Suppose I have `Tutors` who take `online webclasses` and create `learning packs`. Both `online webclasses` and `learning packs`can be rated by `students` and finally a `tutor's` rating is the simple average of all the ratings on his `classes` and `packs`.

This is the table architecture of our current `Ratings` table -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Ratings` (
  `id_rating` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `id_teacher` int(10) unsigned default NULL COMMENT 'the teacher who created the class/pack',
  `id_lp` int(10) unsigned default NULL  COMMENT 'the id of the learning pack',
  `id_wc` int(10) NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'the id of the webclass',
  `id_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'the user who has rated',
  `rate` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `cdate` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `udate` timestamp NULL default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_rating`),
  KEY `Ratings_FKIndex1` (`id_user`),
  KEY `id_lp` (`id_lp`),
  KEY `id_wc` (`id_wc`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Currently, both class and pack ratings are entered into the same table (`id_wc` and `id_lp` are entered accordingly - one is entered and the other is `NULL` for every rating record).

**So, my question is -**
Is this architecture correct or is it better to keep `class` and `pack` ratings separate? Why or why not? I need exactly the same number of `Rating` table fields for both `class` and `pack` rating.

I guess, If class and pack ratings were to be separately found, then separate tables would reduce the number of records to be looked up. But, since in our case only tutor ratings are needed (involves both class and packs), that's why all the ratings are put together.

Comment: Use mySQL workbench it's even made by the mysql developers.

Answer (score 3):

**A bit more detailed model.**

- A teacher at a university can take classes too.
- One class may have more than one teacher.
- There may be several classes on the same subject, taught by different teachers.
- Only students who participate in classes get to vote (rate) the class.
- Learning packs are on a subject (math, biology).
- One learning pack can have several authors.
- Technically, a student can author a learning pack too.
- Only members who use a learning pack get to rate a pack.
- Although authors can vote for packs and teachers can vote for their classes, those votes are ignored.

[image]

**If only interested in the ratings table, you could use:**

[image]

**Or, combine both models into something like:**

[image]

Comment: thanks for answering with these nice pictures but can you please explain a little on how is this architecture better. I am interested only in the ratings table and only upto the system which I have described (only those entities - tutors, classes and packs).

Answer (score 0):

If you think that you'll end up with more entities which will require rating then you need to create something more generic (and not very db-philosophy-friendly).

```
ratings
-------
id
voterClass
voterId
subjectClass
subjectId
vote
date(s)
```

By using this design you forget about FKs and referential integrity. But it's very flexible, and using the right indexes it's very scalable. Also, when entities (subjects) are deleted the votes remain. This design saves you from duplicating fields and tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mySQL workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/). Its cross-platform and works great.

[MySQL workbench visurally see what you are doing with your database. http://diariolinux.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/wb51linuxpreview2a.png](http://diariolinux.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/wb51linuxpreview2a.png)

MySQL workbench Also meets all of your criteria for [general-purpose-remote-data-backup-and-download-including-innodb-support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710954/general-purpose-remote-data-backup-and-download-including-innodb-support) question on stackoverflow

BTW: Use `<ctrl>+<G>` to forward engineer a database.

Comment: @JamesM-SiteGen- Actually I asked for a database design tip/idea here. The tool you suggested may be helpful in general but I can't see how it directly answers my question. If you could elaborate a little? You may consider putting this as a solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710954/general-purpose-remote-data-backup-and-download-including-innodb-support question.