# General purpose remote data backup and download - including InnoDb support

Tags: php, shared-hosting, database-backups

I want a PHP based solution to backup database (only data and not code) of a remote server and download the file. I know that Shell based solutions are better for doing such things (running a shell script on local system and connecting through SSH to remote system) but it is a requirement to have a PHP based solution where knowing a URL and having database credentials is enough for a non-techie to take backups. The PHP script can be uploaded to the remote server and executed.

Following are the **features** I want:-

- Should have support for InnoDb engine at least - foreign key constraints should be exported. No harm if it supports all other engines.
- Should work on all servers, in the presence of the maximum possible amount of restrictions (I know about a few restrictions like `safe_mode` enabled, `exec()`, `system()` functions disabled etc.). I want a very general purpose solution which is guaranteed to work anywhere.
- Process should be password authenticated (asks for database credentials).

Now, I am breaking down things and starting from the very basics. Following are my assumptions of things so far and some **questions**:-

1. I am not sure if system functions like `exec`, `system` etc. can be completely disabled in shared hosting servers or not. If they are disabled such that they cannot be overridden, then the `mysqldump` based solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576025/web-site-backup-in-php/4686627#4686627) will not work universally.
   **Question -** If however only `safe_mode` is on such that system functions can execute on files present inside `safe_mode_exec_dir`, will the solution work securely?
2. I asked a question regarding [security risks of doing this using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680060/security-risks-and-appropriate-measures-while-using-php-for-taking-database-dumps) and understood that the backup file should never be created (I assume, in case of a `mysqldump` based solution, backup file needs to be created first before downloading) in the webspace. So, the solution should not need the backup files to be created there (no problem if creates in other locations).
   **Question -** But, will shared hosting providers allow this?
3. I checked out various general-purpose user contributed PHP classes like [phpmysqldump](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1058-PHP-Backup-a-mysql-database-without-mysqldump.html) etc. and did not find the usage of `mysqldump` based solution using system commands there to take backup. They do things like `SHOW CREATE TABLE` etc. to get all the table creation, data insertion queries and then download those things without actually saving it as a file (so no security risk).
   **Question -** Am I correct to conclude that they do all these things without doing a simple `mysqldump` as given in the solution in the first point because this cannot be a general purpose and secure solution?
   **Question -** Also, I read that there aren't any good ones which work well. I personally used only this [phpmysqldump](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1058-PHP-Backup-a-mysql-database-without-mysqldump.html) and it gives me mysql errors when I try to restore a database with the backup created. The queries in the dump file also look somewhat different from those created by PhpMyAdmin's export module. I also checked a few other free user contributed PHP classes. It looks like most of them do not support InnoDb support and so foriegn key constraints, if present in the database are not present in the export.
   **Question -** The export functionality of PhpMyAdmin itself, if present separately could be the solution for me, I guess. Does anybody know of any stable library like this one?

Comment: Good question. Related (but more on the file backup side): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576025/web-site-backup-in-php

Comment: @Pekka Thanks. Yes I checked your question but I think it deals with some more advanced issues. I am still stuck with more basic things and frankly speaking your issues seem to be going over my head :) If you can at least clear out some basic doubts I have put here? Thanks

Comment: mysqldump defaults to writing on stdout, so you don't actually need temporary files. Not to mention temporaries aren't really a security risk if done properly.

Comment: @derobert: do you mean it is not mandatory to create actual temporary files in case of `mysqldump` and the output can be directly downloaded? Also can you give some more clues on how exactly to do it properly in order to avoid security risks? Thanks

Comment: @Sandeepan yeah, this is a complex issue :) Generally though: Temporary files are not a problem if stored outside the web root. Most providers worth their salt provide the possibility to do that. You can not rely on `mysqldump` being present on shared hosting packages, which is why those scripts use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` etc. However, whatever solution you end up with, **make sure you test it thoroughly**. I have seen and used PHP mysql backup scripts that simply produced broken data.

Comment: I'm aware that this isn't a PHP solution, but I would highly recommend looking at XtraBackup (http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-xtrabackup:start). It's a proven solution, fast, and won't disrupt normal workload. You could always write a PHP script which would execute this (or any other tool).

Answer (score 2):

### What I think you should do:

I Think you should install phpmyadmin on your server, this will allow you to access your database from work/school/cafe/etc, MySQL-workbench is more advanced and gives you more features so you can deal with changing the structure and editing any rows/columns, relations, and much more, look at phpmyadmin's features it has most if not all.

### phpmyadmin it works in any web-browser:

I really recommended phpMyAdmin it has many SQL features to help you deal with everything when it comes to the MySQL database if you are using innoDB then you get even more features such as relation-ships between tables.

#### [phpMyAdmin](http://phpmyadmin.net/) has the following features:

- Intuitive web interface
- Support for most MySQL features:
- browse and drop databases, tables, views, fields and indexes
- create, copy, drop, rename and alter databases, tables, fields and indexes
- maintenance server, databases and tables, with proposals on server configuration
- execute, edit and bookmark any SQL-statement, even batch-queries
- manage MySQL users and privileges
- manage stored procedures and triggers
- Import data from CSV and SQL
- Export data to various formats: CSV, SQL, XML, PDF, ISO/IEC 26300 - OpenDocument Text and Spreadsheet, Word, Excel, LATEX and others
- Administering multiple servers
- Creating PDF graphics of your database layout
- Creating complex queries using Query-by-example (QBE)
- Searching globally in a database or a subset of it
- Transforming stored data into any format using a set of predefined functions, like displaying BLOB-data as image or download-link
- And much more...

Everything you listed above is included in phpMyAdmin, if you are running debian or Debian-based system simply run:

```
root@debian:~ # aptitude install phpmyadmin
root@arch:~ # pacman -S phpmyadmin
```

BTW: if you are not using Apache or lighttpd for the http-server you will need to read through the conf files for phpmyadmin and then write up the required conf script for phpmyadmin to work with your http-server.

### [MySQL workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/). Its cross-platform and works great.

[MySQL workbench visurally see what you are doing with your database. http://diariolinux.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/wb51linuxpreview2a.png](http://diariolinux.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/wb51linuxpreview2a.png)

BTW: Use `<ctrl>+<G>` to forward engineer a database, It took me a while to find out for to do this.

### Stand alone perl file that works just after you configure it: (untested)

```
use DBI;
my $user = "username";   # MySQL Username
my $pass = "xxxx";       # MySQL Password
my $host = "localhost";  # MySQL Host
my $mydb = "zzzz";       # MySQL Database
my $file = "test.sql";   # Import file
my $sqlServer = "mysql"; # What sql-server are we using, oracle/mysql/etc
    # I would use the following method to configure it, though the above works fine too.
($user,$pass,$host,$mydb,$file,sqlServer) = (
    "username",  # MySQL Username
    "password",  # MySQL Password
    "localhost", # MySQL Host
    "myDB",      # MySQL Database
    "test.sql",  # Imported file
    "mysql"      # What sql-server are we using, oracle/mysql/etc
);
    # Now lets connect to the MySQL server.
my $dbh  = DBI->connect("DBI:$sqlServer:$mydb:$host",$user,$pass)or die DBI->errstr();
    # Lets now open the .sql file.
open(INPUT,$file);
    # Now lets run each sql-statement.
while ($line = <INPUT>){
    print $line;
    $dbh->do($line);
    print "Query failed (run manually):\n$line\n\n ". $dbh->errstr()."\n" if $dbh->errstr();
}
    # Now close the file.
close(INPUT);
```

Comment: I am well aware of the features supported by PhpMyAdmin and I have already mentioned the export module of PhpMyAdmin. The other features of PhpMyAdmin do not actually help in solving this problem. Only a working export script (like I have said, a separate working export module of PhpMyAdmin) would be a good solution (a single script instead of a whole web application). If you know about any such similar working script I would really appreciate that. Thanks.

Comment: @Sandeepan @Sandeepan Nath : I added another entry above, I will also include a single stand alone script that will take a parameter for the SQL script. MySQL workbench is the best option though, I do know its another program, but as it works on most if not all operating-systems.

Comment: @Sandeepan Nath : But first I need to know are you running an operating system with perl? if yes I can give you a simple script that takes a parameter and sill read out the SQL commands to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMyAdmin is a great solution in general but may be overkill if you only ever want to do backups.  If you want a universal solution then absolutely don't rely on exec being available.  PHP combined with the right SQL queries (as you have noted in your point 3.)  can provide you with all the information you need and will always work.

Comment: If you know about any such properly tested script I would really appreciate that. Thanks.

Comment: @Sandeepan Nath It's very easy to write one yourself.  I've done it for a production environment.  I'm sorry I can't provide details, but if you know your way around SQL you can work out the necessary queries to run.  Look up the DESCRIBE mysql query to get a table's info, that's probably the only tricky bit.

Answer (score 0):

In my own experience, relying  on PHP based backup solution is VERY bad idea. If you are dealing with large backups, PHP can easily fail (due to timeouts, memory consumption or something undefined).

We have been successfully using Bacula (http://www.bacula.org/en/) for years now on our un*x servers. Did our own backup scripts which do whatever we want to do. You need to have shell access to server off course.

If you need simple backup php based solution, you are best with writing your own. :)